# Concatenate data from multiple rows

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| ks_id | direction | time | text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1a | down | 1 |  |
| 1a | up | 3 | h |
| 1b | down | 4 |  |
| 1b | up | 7 | e |

I would like to transform this to a dataframe where the different directions are in one line, e.g.:

| ks_id | down_time | up_time | text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1a | 1 | 3 | h |
| 1b | 4 | 7 | e |

I've tried grouping by ks_id and then mutating, but have not had success with this. How can I convert the df as above?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  ks_id = c("1a", "1a", "1b", "1b"),
  direction = c("down", "up", "down", "up"),
  time = c(1L, 3L, 4L, 7L),
  text = c(NA, "h", NA, "e")
)

df %>% 
  pivot_wider(ks_id, names_from = "direction", values_from = c(time, text)) %>%
  unite(text, c("text_up", "text_down"), na.rm = T) 

#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#>   ks_id time_down time_up text 
#>   <chr>     <int>   <int> <chr>
#> 1 1a            1       3 h    
#> 2 1b            4       7 e
```

**Explanation**

The function `pivot_wider` does what it is schematized in the following figure:

[image]

(Source: https://ab604.github.io/docs/coding-together-2019/data-wrangle-2.html)

With your data, one gets:

```
  ks_id time_down time_up text_down text_up
  <chr>     <int>   <int> <chr>     <chr>  
1 1a            1       3 NA        h      
2 1b            4       7 NA        e
```

As you see, there are two text columns, which need to be unified. To accomplish that, one can use `unite`, whose action is schematized in the following figure:

[image]

(Source: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html)

You may want to read the sections 12.3 and 12.4 of the following book:

[R for Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/index.html)

Comment: Interesting! Could you explain a bit what's going on here?

Comment: I have just added an explanation to my answer, @Adam_G. Hope that helps you!

Comment: Thanks! This is a great explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Just `reshape it.

```
reshape(dat, idvar='ks_id', timevar='direction', direction='wide')[-3]
#   ks_id time.down time.up text.up
# 1    1a         1       3       h
# 3    1b         4       7       e
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(ks_id = c("1a", "1a", "1b", "1b"), direction = c("down", 
"up", "down", "up"), time = c(1L, 3L, 4L, 7L), text = c(NA, "h", 
NA, "e")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```